# Display custom category attribute on category page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, category, attributes

I've created a module to add a custom category attribute (heading) to a category page. The attribute displays in the admin and I can save the value. I'm wondering what is the best way to display this on a category page?

`Example/CategoryHeading/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Example_CategoryHeading" setup_version="0.0.1">
        </module>
    </config>
```

`Example/CategoryHeading/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
<?php

namespace Example\CategoryHeading\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
    ModuleContextInterface,
    ModuleDataSetupInterface,
    InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'heading', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Heading',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 3,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]);
    }
}
```

`Example/CategoryHeading/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="heading" sortOrder="49" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Heading</label>
                <scopeLabel>[STORE VIEW]</scopeLabel>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

`Example/CategoryHeading/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.view.container">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.heading" template="Example_CategoryHeading::category/heading.phtml" before="category.description"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

`Example/CategoryHeading/view/frontend/templates/category/heading.phtml`

```
<?php
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis

/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 */
?>
<div class="category-heading">
    <h1>
        <span>
            <?php
                $_category = $block->getCurrentCategory();

                if ($_heading = $_category->getHeading()) {
                    echo $_heading;
                } else {
                    echo $_category->getName();
                }
            ?>
        </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

`Example/CategoryHeading/registration.php`

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Example_CategoryHeading',
    __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is great as it is, especially for a new contributor.

I have spotted 2 issues and a possible improvement in the layout/template. Using ViewModel does allow to delegate the logic from your template to a singleton model whereas Block are much heavier and coupled with Magento core (even reusing a core Magento block is not necessarily a best option)

below is my setup

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\CategoryHeading\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CategorySetup
     */
    private $categorySetup;

    public function __construct(
        CategorySetup $categorySetup
    ) {
        $this->categorySetup = $categorySetup;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup(); // you forgot this

        $this->categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'heading',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Heading',
                'visible' => 1,
                'visible_on_front' => 1,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();  // you forgot this
    }
}
```

my layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.view.container">
            <block name="category.heading" template="Mbs_CategoryHeading::category/heading.phtml" before="category.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Mbs\CategoryHeading\ViewModel\CategoryViewModel</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

my template is:

```
<?php
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis

/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 * @var $viewModel \Mbs\CategoryHeading\ViewModel\CategoryViewModel
 */
$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
?>
<div class="category-heading">
    <h1>
        <span>
            <?php echo $viewModel->getCurrentCategoryHeading(); ?>
        </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

and finally ViewModel

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\CategoryHeading\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class CategoryViewModel implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategoryHeading()
    {
        $currentCategory = $this->registry->registry('current_category');

        if ($currentCategory) {
            $_heading = trim($currentCategory->getHeading());

            if ($_heading === '') {
                $_heading = $currentCategory->getName();
            }
        }

        return $_heading;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code compliment.

I made the adjustments you suggested as using a ViewModel seemed like a better approach. After making those adjustments the changes still weren’t visible on the frontend but a re-index did the trick.

Comment: flush block_html and layout cache should have been sufficient. Great it helped you, thanks for feedback.. it feels good to be helpful during this pandemic :-)